# backslash removed from file path on Jenkins Pipeline on windows node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have a jenkins pipeline file, this stage is executed on a windows node (the master is on a container running on Mac). I'm trying to copy an exe file from a directory in the slave to the current working directory on the same slave (the one created by the workspace)

if i do this on my jenkins file:

```
def myPath = "c:\\Users\\user1\\jenkins\a\\b\\c\\d\\"
sh "ls $myPath"
```

This works just fine. However, this needs to use the current working directory.

so i'm doing something like this

```
def fileDirDestination = "\\b\\c\\d\\""
def fullFileDest = "${env.WORKSPACE}" + fileDirDestination
```

and by doing that i end up without any backslasshes. I have also tried four quotes """" and four backslashes

```
cusersuser1jenkinsabcd
```

I have also tried this :

```
def destinationFilePath = new FilePath(channel, build.workspace.toString() + "\\\\a\\\\b\\\\c\\\\d")
destinationFilePath.list()
```

and this actually results in the same issue mentioned above (a path without backslashes)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I faced with same issue and found a bug related to this problem: [Jenkins Jira issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-44482?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel)

As a temporary solution, I used WORKSPACE redefinition like this:

```
environment {
    
    WORKSPACE = WORKSPACE.replaceAll('\\\\', '/')
```